# Apache server at new AWS EC2 instance is not reachable

Tags: debian, apache-httpd, amazon-ec2, aws

I am not able to access my web server I recently set up on Ubuntu AWS EC2 instance:

```
client:~ user$ curl yyy.yyy.yyy.yyyy
curl: (7) Failed to connect to yyy.yyy.yyy.yyyy port 80: Operation timed out
```

Apache is up and running at the AWS instance:

```
ubuntu@server:~$ sudo service apache2 status
* apache2 is running
```

and the port 80 is opened

```
ubuntu@server:~$ sudo netstat -plunt | grep apache2
tcp6     0    0 :::80                 :::*                  LISTEN    2968/apache2
```

I am not that experienced in setting up web servers so far, but as I know Apache should be accessible right after it was installed. What might be wrong in my case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The web server seems to be listening to the actual port and running, accordingly to your `netstat`.

You have got to open the firewall rule in the AWS console.

Have a look at this: [Authorizing Inbound Traffic for Your Linux Instances](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/authorizing-access-to-an-instance.html)

Change SSH from the quoted test to HTTP.

> To enable network access to your instance, you must allow inbound
>   traffic to your instance. To open a port for inbound traffic, add a
>   rule to a security group that you associated with your instance when
>   you launched it.
>
> To add a rule to a security group for inbound SSH traffic using the
>   console
>
> In the navigation pane of the Amazon EC2 console, choose Instances.
>   Select your instance and look at the Description tab; Security groups
>   lists the security groups that are associated with the instance.
>   Choose view rules to display a list of the rules that are in effect
>   for the instance.
>
> In the navigation pane, choose Security Groups. Select one of the
>   security groups associated with your instance.
>
> In the details pane, on the Inbound tab, choose Edit. In the dialog,
>   choose Add Rule, and then select SSH from the Type list.
>
> In the Source field, specify the public IP address of your computer,
>   in CIDR notation. For example, if your IP address is 203.0.113.25,
>   specify 203.0.113.25/32 to list this single IP address in CIDR
>   notation. If your company allocates addresses from a range, specify
>   the entire range, such as 203.0.113.0/24.
>
> Choose Save.